# linq javascript library with typescript es6 import syntax

Tags: typescript

I am using linq (npm linq) with the linq.d.ts files off definitely typed however I cannot get it working with the ES 6 syntax.

I tried the normal `import {Enumerable} from "linq"` however it refused to find `"linq"`. I changed the descriptor to have `declare module "linq"` whereas normally it would not have quotes. Now linq resolves but I have to use the EnumerableStatic but the output code needs to have `Enumerable` not `EnumerableStatic`. I thought I could get around it by doing `import {EnumerableStatic as Enumerable} from "linq"` however this fails to resolve properly.

Has anyone had this working and if how do you import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition file needs to be updated:

1. The documentation and definition file have different case for the function names than the 3.0.5 release. For example `Enumerable.From` is now `Enumerable.from`. You'll need to update the definition file with these changes.
2. The definition file currently doesn't allow external modules. Add this to it:

   ```
   declare module "linq" {
       export = Enumerable;
   }
   ```
3. Then since it uses `module.exports = Enumerable` in the JavaScript code, you'll need to import it like this:

   ```
   import * as Enumerable from "linq";
   ```

Comment: Hey, yeah currently I have done as you mention and moved the `EnumerableStatic` method calls into the module as function exports and done the `import * as Enumerable from "linq"` but if the method names are out of date too then thats a pain :(

Comment: @Grofit: Well, it seems that the author only renamed function names from `FunctionName` to `functionName`. That's not that bad. Simply use the `linq.d.ts` file and make as the changes as you need them and then send a pull request to https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped. (overhead: half an hour top ;))

Comment: now it said require not found, so i add requirejs, yet now it generate errors, and say, linq is not loaded, i doubt if the linq.js  *.js file has the linq module as well as the ts. :| what should i do? are there any packages other than linq.js which is not linq.js, and linq which is the linq.js it self on NPM package manager?

Comment: i have trouble with ver 3.0.4-beta5, i can't import 'linqjs' in ts class but, in linq.js file, on browser, goes to amd if, and return define('linqjs'....)

Comment: I followed all steps from here and was all ok : https://github.com/dflor003/typed-linq

Answer (score 2):

I created `main.ts` file:

```
/// <reference path="typings/linq/linq.d.ts" />

import { Enumerable } from 'linq';
```

I get `TS2307: Cannot find module 'linq'.` error from the compiler. When you add some debugging statements to the `tsc.js`, you get that this import leads to running [loadModuleFromNodeModules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/program.ts#L117) function and `failedLookups` are:

```
[ '/var/www/TypeScript-Playground/node_modules/linq.ts',
  '/var/www/TypeScript-Playground/node_modules/linq.tsx',
  '/var/www/TypeScript-Playground/node_modules/linq.d.ts',
  '/var/www/TypeScript-Playground/node_modules/linq/index.ts',
  '/var/www/TypeScript-Playground/node_modules/linq/index.tsx',
  '/var/www/TypeScript-Playground/node_modules/linq/index.d.ts',
  '/var/www/node_modules/linq.ts',
  '/var/www/node_modules/linq.tsx',
  '/var/www/node_modules/linq.d.ts',
  '/var/www/node_modules/linq/package.json',
  '/var/www/node_modules/linq/index.ts',
  '/var/www/node_modules/linq/index.tsx',
  '/var/www/node_modules/linq/index.d.ts',
  '/var/node_modules/linq.ts',
  '/var/node_modules/linq.tsx',
  '/var/node_modules/linq.d.ts',
  '/var/node_modules/linq/package.json',
  '/var/node_modules/linq/index.ts',
  '/var/node_modules/linq/index.tsx',
  '/var/node_modules/linq/index.d.ts',
  '/node_modules/linq.ts',
  '/node_modules/linq.tsx',
  '/node_modules/linq.d.ts',
  '/node_modules/linq/package.json',
  '/node_modules/linq/index.ts',
  '/node_modules/linq/index.tsx',
  '/node_modules/linq/index.d.ts' ]
```

so that means that your file `/var/www/TypeScript-Playground/node_modules/linq/linq.js` is not found.

I would repost your question to [Gitter](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript) or to [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues). Also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2242 issue says that:

> In TypeScript 1.5, a source file is considered an external module if it contains at least one of the following:
>
> A top-level declaration that specifies an export modifier.
>
> An new ES6 export or import declaration of any form.
>
> An original TypeScript export-equals assignment of the form export = Point.
>
> An original TypeScript import-equals statement of the form import Math = require("math").

I don't think that `linq` follows the points.

Comment: This was originally asked in gitter, then there was not much in the way of answers so it was posted here instead.

Answer (score 1):

> There is also a promising looking linq-ts library, written i
>   Typescript from scratch

The library was renamed to linq-es2015. It uses all the latest features of language and theoretically much faster. Example: https://github.com/ENikS/LINQ/tree/examples/TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

I found a library, [retyped-linq-tsd-ambient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retyped-linq-tsd-ambient), that installs with **npm**.  It has a file, ATW, linq.3.0.3-Beta4.d.ts - which contains the lowercase naming.

I added a reference to that file:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/retyped-linq-tsd-ambient/linq.3.0.3-Beta4.d.ts" />
```

... and was unable to import the linq.js module. Then I added the snippet mentioned in David Sherret's answer:

```
declare module "linq" {
     export = Enumerable;
}
```

And I am able to use the linq library in my typescript code with intellisence.

**However:** The typing is weak compared to the C# version, using "any" and untyped collections instead of inferred types and typed collections.  With the excellent features of the typescript language, it should be possible to get closer to the C# experience.

**Note:** There is also a promising looking [linq-ts](https://github.com/ENikS/LINQ/) library, written i Typescript from scratch.  This seems to have much stronger typing.  Unfortunately I was not able to get it to compile / work in my project, due to some es6(-shim) dependencies.